# Copy all the array elements into another array

Tags: c, arrays

I done with my logic which is actually used to copy a Array elements into another Array but in the final output(Point 1) of printing statement is not working well as I expecting.

I'm expecting to print the copied value to print but its not showing the last element of the array.

```
Eg: a[] = 1,2,3 
    b[] = 8,9

Expecting o/p: 1,2,3,8,9

   Actual o/p: 1,2,3,8
```

Code I have so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
       int a[50],b[50],m,n,loc;

       printf("Enter size of 1st Elements:\n");

       scanf("%d", &m);

       printf("Enter %d Elements:\n", m);

       for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
       {
           scanf("%d", &a[i]);
       }

       printf("Enter size of 2nd Element:\n");

       scanf("%d", &n);

       printf("Enter %d Elements\n", n);

       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
           scanf("%d", &b[i]);
       }

       printf("Enter the Location to insert:\n");

       scanf("%d", &loc);

      for(int i=m-1;i>=loc;i--)
      {
          a[i+n] = a[i];

      }

      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
          a[loc+i] = b[i];
      }

      printf("Result of final Array is\n");

      for(int i=0;i<=m+n;i++)  //point-1
        {
          printf("%d \n", a[i]);
        }

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The number of elements after inserting is `n+m`, but you're only printing `m+1` elements.

Comment: @Barmar Its working after printing m+n. Ty

Comment: There's a function called [memcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) that will copy an array for you.   Also, [memmove](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) for overlapping buffers.

Comment: If your question is answered in a comment, please put at least the essentials in a real answer and mark it. This site is not for just the questioners but mainly for others with similar questions. It saves time for helpers to not have to read already answered questions, and it helps those others when they see it is answered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Divide your code into functions, which should do only one thing, separate IO (input output via stdin/out) from actual work on the data. Then inspecting the parameters as a sense-full checkpoint will usually catch most bugs. This is probably just the 1000st simple array i.e. loop error, obscured by mixing all into one function. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
A minor mistake fixed in the code. Added the size of n in the final printing loop (Point -1).

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[50],b[50],m,n;
    int loc;

    printf("Enter the size of 1st Element\n");

    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("Enter %d elements\n", m);

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter the size of 2nd Elements\n");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter %d elements\n", n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter the location to insert\n");

    scanf("%d", &loc);

    for(int i=m-1;i>=loc;i--)
    {
        a[i+n] = a[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[loc+i] = b[i];
    }

    printf("Final Elements\n");

    for(int i=0;i<m+n;i++) //Point 1
    {
        printf("%d \n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```